# Generic method throws COM exception on return

Tags: c#, generics, ms-word

I have an application using the office interop libraries (Word and Excel 2007) library version 12.0 and I have a generic method for executing tasks with a timeout in case Office stops responding for some reason but when the method returns its value it throws an exception stating the Com object can't be used when separated from its rcw.

**Method:**

```
public static R ExecuteOfficeTimoutAction<R>(Func<R> ToExecute, TimeSpan TimeOut)
{
    object returnVal = new OfficeEmptyReturn(); // Empty Class Used With Reflection To Tell If There Was Really A Value Returned

    try
    {
        Exception threadError = null;

        System.Threading.Thread timedThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                returnVal = ToExecute();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                threadError = ex;
            }
        });
        timedThread.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Normal;
        timedThread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        timedThread.Start();
        timedThread.Join(TimeOut);

        if (threadError != null)
        {
            throw threadError;
        }

        if (timedThread.ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped)
        {
            bool abortCalled = false;
            bool processKilled = false;

            int waitTime = 0;

            do
            {
                if (!abortCalled)
                {
                    timedThread.Abort();
                    abortCalled = true;
                }

                if (waitTime < 2500)
                {
                    waitTime += 250;

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
                }
                else if (!processKilled)
                {
                    processKilled = true;
                    foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process process in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
                    {
                        if (process.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("winword.exe") || process.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("excel.exe"))
                        {
                            process.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new TimeoutException("The Timeout Action Could Not Be Terminated");
                }
            }
            while (!(timedThread.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Aborted || timedThread.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return (R)returnVal; // Throws Exception Here
}
```

**Method Where It Throws An Error:**

```
public Document GetDocument(string FilePath)
{
    Document newDoc = null;

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilePath))
    {
        if (File.Exists(FilePath) && IsWordDoc(new FileInfo(FilePath)))
        {
            if (IsActive)
            {
                if (FilePath.Length < 255)
                {
                    newDoc = ExecuteOfficeTimoutAction<Application, Document>((Application app) => 
                    {
                        Document tempDoc = app.Documents.Open(FilePath, Type.Missing, true);
                        return tempDoc; 
                    }, App, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));

                    if (newDoc == null || newDoc is OfficeEmptyReturn)
                    {
                        newDoc = null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The Word Document's Full Path Must Be Shorter Than 255 Characters To Be Reached");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The Word Application Must Be Open To Process Word Data");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("The Word File Did Not Exist At The Specified Path");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("The File Path Was Null");
    }

    return newDoc;
}
```

The App object being passed in is a static `Word.Application` object stored in a field within the containing word class so that it is visible to all applicable methods and disposed of appropriately when no longer needed.

I don't see why it would be giving this exception when returning a value, even if it is a com object.

My desired outcome is for the method to return the value generated by the passed Func, throw the exception generated by said delegate or return OfficeEmptyReturn.

Any help or pointers with this would be greatly appreciated.

Side note, I do have fallback error handling for when the office application is terminated outside the application automating it, I would open the task manager and manually terminate word when it froze my code then it would continue but that is not an acceptable outcome.

Comment: Is this code being run from a desktop app or is it being run from inside a windows service or IIS Website?

Comment: Whatever real problem you're trying to solve, you made it a hundred times worse.  COM objects created on an STA thread are associated with that thread, they automatically die when the thread terminates.  So yes, you are supposed to get that exception.  .NET resources are also never shy about pointing out why using Thread.Abort() is such a bad idea.  Pretty likely that whatever you'll do next will cause the finalizer thread to deadlock.  You'll have to throw this away.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It is being run within a desktop environment.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah that would make sense, I didn't realize that. Is there a way to run office action without office giving the chance of locking up that you can think of?

Comment: @HansPassant would running the action in a MTA solve that problem or do you recommend a different solution all together?

Comment: @HansPassant that was certainly the problem. I changed the apartment to be a MTA and slightly changed the func passed when getting the document to return the return of app.ducments.open() instead of storing the document object before returning it. Thank you for the help. If you could post your comment as an answer I would be happy to accept it.